# vba getelelementbyclassname()

Tags: vba, web-scraping, web-crawler, getelementsbyclassname, getelementsbytagname

I'm beginner

I am studying about web scraping but, I have some problem i can't solve by myself. 
I need your soultion.

I'm finding it that  how to input getelementbytagname(a)  in getelementbyclassname() with for function

like this:

[image]

```
For i = 0 To 23

Cells(3 + i, 5) = doc.getElementsByClassName("name").getElementsByTagName("a")(i).innerText
Cells(3 + i, 5).WrapText = False

Next i

'=========================================================
'above code
'this was error
```

what is problem?
help me. 
thanks a lot

I'm waiting your answer

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a node list, so you'll have to nest this loop in another loop that iterates across `class = "name"` elements.

Comment: Set this `doc.getElementsByTagName("a")` to a `HTMLElementCollection` and then loop through this, although you may be able to do both using a `queryselector`, like `doc.querySelectorAll("a.classname")`  Something along these lines `Dim c As MSHTML.HTMLElementCollection
Set c = d.querySelectorAll("a.class")`